# Conceptual doubt regarding electrolytic cells involving acids

Tags: electrochemistry

Consider the following cell

Ag(s) | AgIO3(s) | Ag+
(x M), HIO3 (1 M) || $Zn^{2+}$
(1 M) | Zn(s)

My doubt is not regarding the full calculation of the EMF , but the meaning of ' 1 M HIO3 '.

What I mean to say is , does '1M' mean the concentration of HIO3 at time 't'? (the time at which nerst equation has been applied) or at t = 0?

This is because everywhere on the internet, for the calculation of [IO3-] , the INITIAL concentration of HIO3 has been taken as 1M , which I fail to understand why. As per my knowledge , we have applied the nerst equation at any time 't' and thus involving the reaction quotient at that instant, and hence the initial concentration of HIO3 should not be 1M, but more than that (and the concentration after considering its dissociation , i.e. , c-c$\alpha$ , is 1M).

So is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think you are correct. According to me, the voltage of the cell keeps decreasing in magnitude until the reaction hits equilibrium and the cell potential is 0. So if you were to find the potential at time t (considering c=1M at t=0), the value of $t$ needs to be given. Otherwise you’ll have the value of $E_{\text{cell}}$ at the time when c=1M. It might be helpful if you link the solutions on the internet which give rise to the confusion.

Comment: Both concentrations  [$\ce{HIO3}$] and [$\ce{Zn^{2+}}$] are  to be considered as $\pu{1 M}$ at $\pu{t = 0}$.

Comment: @Maurice so is it a convention which i might have missed out that all concentrations mentioned in the IUPAC shorthand notation of the cell are to be considered at t=0?

Comment: @insipidintegrator thanks for the reply, i dont think giving the link wuld be of much use as I already mentioned what i didnt feel right about them. Anyways , there IS one video which is not in english(It doesnt matter though, the solution he has written is in english) i'll link it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rjk_U2zz6bo . See the right side of the greenboard. Clearly he has taken the written concentration as the initial one.

Comment: @Hsrah. You seem to forget that the cell tension, as determined by Nernst's law, does not depend on the time. It is measured with no current flowing out of the cell.

Comment: @Maurice thank for replying, I must admit was not at all aware of that fact. Could you please provide me with some text for further reading because I did not find any text available to me which has that concept.

Comment: @Hsrah. Sorry for having forgotten you for one month. You find plenty of texts by typing "Internal resistance of a cell" on Google. The first reference goes like this. ...The nominal potential difference (E) of a cell is always greater than the measured value V measured across a cell, if this cell is delivering a current.
Ex.: The potential difference across a cell when no current flows is 3 V. When the current I = 0.37 Amp is flowing, the measured initial potential difference falls to 2.8 Volts, if the internal resistance (r) of the cell is 0.54 ohm, according to the formula E = V + Ir

Answer (score -1):

I view this as relating to a spontaneous galvanic cell involving the anodic corrosion of Zinc metal with noble Silver metal in the presence of Iodic acid.

In that event, the smallest amount of $\ce{HIO3}$ with a starting amount of 1 mole of Zinc is just 1 mole corresponding to a possible targeted formation of $\ce{IO3Zn+}$ ([as, for example, noted in this source](https://www.americanelements.com/zinc-iodate-7790-37-6)).

Note: The notation employed references an electrolysis cell involving the reverse reaction.

My comment on Iodic acid is the same 1 mole (or more, see, for example, [Question (40) here](https://chemistry.sites.clemson.edu/genchem/Courses/1020Docs/Spring%202010/Mock3.pdf) or [Q (16) here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Physical_Chemistry_For_JEE_Main_Advanced/tIuxDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Ag(s)+%7C+AgIO3(s)+%7C+Ag%2B+(x+M),+HIO3+(1+M)+%7C%7C+Zn2%2B+(1+M)+%7C+Zn(s)&pg=PT485&printsec=frontcover)).

In short, the mole ratio between Zinc and Iodic acid is more variable (hence, the seeming discrepancy) depending on the possible targeted speciation of the Zn.